# Trouble getting an element to be clicked using Selenium

Tags: selenium, click, webdriverwait

I am trying to go to the below URL

```
https://twitter.com/explore
```

Enter HBO Max in the text box which I locate using

```
By.cssSelector("input[placeholder='Search Twitter']")
```

and then I want to select the HBO Max option that appears in the dropdown. My locator for the element to be selected is

```
By.xpath("//div[@role='option']//li/div/div[2]")
```

Sometimes the element gets clicked and I go to the new page, sometimes not. I have in my framework waited for the element to be clickable using WebDriverWait. The element is both visible and enabled because I print these values before I click the element.

Additional debugging steps performed -

1. Click using JavaScript seems to have the same behavior.
2. I believe I am using the right locator because the mouse event gets generated for this element.
3. Thread.Sleep seems to work suggesting that perhaps a timing issue

Any inputs would be great.

Answer (score 0):

```
try:
    myElem = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'ID')))
    print("Page is ready!")
except TimeoutException:
    print("Loading took too much time!")
```

Try this !
what it does : It wait until the specific element of the site is loaded. If it takes more time than specified will just give you an output as  "loading took too.........."

You can modify the time required to wait.

Comment: No, this is not it. My framework already waits for an element to be present before taking any action. Furthermore like I mentioned the element is both enabled and visible as well. I suspect that even thought the element is there and clickable, the event handlers for the click event haven’t registered to the element by the time I click it. There are workarounds. For example I can always create a custom Expected Wait condition waiting for the element to be clickable plus the URL to change on a click. But was more interested in trying to understand why it’s not working here

Comment: I checked the, twitter webpage, searched hbo max, the xpath seems incorrect. what I got is that xpath for hbo profile is "//*[@id="typeaheadDropdown-4"]/div[6]/div/li/div"

Comment: for only searching the first suggestion, then the xpath i got is "//*[@id="typeaheadDropdown-4"]/div[2]/div/div/div"